# PHP/MYSQL - Can't find why this code sends mail more than twice

Tags: php, mysql, email

Alright, I'm starting to pull my hair and I need some help :)

Here is my file which is used to select activated emails from users and send them some sort of newsletter.

**Content of the newsletter.php**

```
<?php
//Include configuration file
include 'config/config.php'; 
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Define messages
//Error messages
define('ERROR_MESSAGE_SUBJECT', 'Enter subject');
define('ERROR_MESSAGE_CONTENT', 'Enter some content');

//Define variables
$errorFlag = false;
$to = array();

//Grab variables
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $newsletterSubject = check_input($_POST['newsletterSubject']);
    $newsletterContent = $_POST['newsletterContent'];       

    if(!$newsletterSubject) {
        $errorSubject = ERROR_MESSAGE_SUBJECT;  
        $errorFlag = true;
    }
    if(!$newsletterContent) {
        $errorContent = ERROR_MESSAGE_CONTENT;
        $errorFlag = true;  
    }
}
?>
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post">
    <label>Naslov newsletter-a: <?php echo '<span class="error">'.$errorSubject.'</span>';?></label>
    <input type="text" class="linput rounded" name="newsletterSubject">

    <label>Sadržaj newsletter-a: <?php echo '<span class="error">'.$errorContent.'</span>';?></label>
    <textarea name="newsletterContent" class="rounded"></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" class="submit button rounded" name="newsletterSend" value="Pošalji newsletter korisnicima">
</form>
<?php
                if (!$errorFlag) {                  
                    echo '
                        <div class="heading">
                            <h1>Sending statistic</h1>
                        </div>';

                    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE active=:active');
                    $query->bindValue(':active', '1');  
                    $query->execute();
                    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $i=1;
                    while($row = $query->fetch()) { 
                        $to[] = $row['email'];
                    }
                    print_r($to);

                    if(!empty($to)) {
                        foreach($to as $mail) {
                            $headers = "From: " . $fromEmail . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $fromEmail . "\r\n";
                            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                            $message = '<html><body>';
                            $message .= $newsletterContent;
                            $message .= '</body></html>';
                            mail($mail, $newsletterSubject, $message, $headers);
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
              ?>
```

After selecting active emails from database, array $to contains:

```
Array ( [0] => somemail1@domain.com [1] => somemail2@domain.com )
```

And that is correct, but both emails will receive 2 emails, so 4 in total. Normally one email should receive one newsletter.

And there is also something else strange, when first newsletter is received, it contains subject and message. However second newsletter doesnt contain anything except 'to' field.
**So to sum up, this file sends two emails per one email in database.**

I tried to create test file with same array and this is content of it:

**test.php**

```
<?php
$fromEmail = 'from@mydomain.com';
$to = array('somemail1@domain.com', 'somemail2@domain.com');
print_r($to);

foreach($to as $mail) {
    $headers = "From: " . $fromEmail . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $fromEmail . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= $newsletterContent;
    $message .= '</body></html>';
    mail($mail, $newsletterSubject, $message, $headers);
    $i++;
}   
?>
```

This test file sends normal email - one email per one email. So server configuration should be okay.

Comment: Does removing the mail() function call not send any e-mail at all ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's because your send code isn't inside the code block which checks that it is POST, so it sends once when you load the page and again when you fill in the form and submit it.

Move the whole if (!$errorFlag) block into the if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') block.

Comment: I move and it work! However still I cant understand why before it didn't worked. Let me explain: At my example there is $errorFlag = false on top of the page, and with that i assure that it will be false on every load. After that, only if there is $_POST request $errorFlag can be set. But its not because i have to fill subject and content of the newsletter. So before sending out emails, $errorFlag is still false and line if (!$errorFlag) {..} is there to prevent this what you have explained. Why my logic fails? :D

Comment: If $errorFlag is false, the code block (!$errorFlag) will execute. So when you first load the page it's false because you set it to false and so that block executes. After you submit the form, provided there are no errors it's still false and that code block executes again.